# How to search for code in all projects simultaneously?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I'm dealing with a **GitLab Community Edition** `13.10.1`.
At the moment there are about a hundred small projects on this.

By selecting a project it is possible to search for specific code within all its files, but if instead I go to the GitLab search and select "Any" project, the "Code" tab is no longer visible.

[image]

Is there a way to do a code search, but within all the existing existing projects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [GitLab Advanced Search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search.html) to search for code if you are subscribed to the premium tier.

Another option would be to use the opensource [gitlab-search](https://github.com/phillipj/gitlab-search) tool if you are using the community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Gitlab API [rate limit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/rate_limits.html), [gitlab-search](https://github.com/phillipj/gitlab-search) will not work properly, as an open-source alternative you can try [gitlab-finder](https://github.com/ldbglobe/gitlab-finder) instead. it introduces sleep time between calls as a workaround.

**note** that like @danielnelz said, advanced gitlab search is a premium feature on gitlab, so if you already have a license just use the existing functionality.